# IE drop down list not working, className and id's is dynamic

Tags: html, automation, ie-automation

Can someone help me on web page automation.

I have a dynamic web page that needs to be automated using VBA Excel. But the problem is when it is dynamic and its className and Id's get changes every time web page refreshed.

I need to click on a drop down list (made from `ul > li` elements) on web page and select 1 item out of 3.

Attached is for your reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj6v1.png)

Comment: Does the `<div class="options-list">...</div>` remain constant? if so, you should be able to hook into this element, then click the "Nth" `<li>` element nested child inside it.

Comment: Hi scunliffe, will really appreciate if can you please help me with the code.